# Evitar sobreposição de ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Estou com um problema com os `ListView`s que é o seguinte: Trabalho com 2 `ListView`s e quero que quando eu clique em um, que o outro desapareça e que não que fiquem sobrepostos como tem ficado. Só quero que quando eu clique e abra o primeiro `ListView` e logo em seguida antes se eu clicar para abrir o segundo `ListView`, que o primeiro se feche.

O código que estou usando é esse e também pode ser visto pela imagem a seguir:

```java
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.like:

            preecheListLike();

            listaLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            listaLike.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String nome = listaLike.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                    setMarker(latit, longi, nome, true, position);
                    listaLike.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    setUpMap();
                }

            });

            break;
        case R.id.dislike:

            preecheListDislike();
            listaDislike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //listaLike.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            listaDislike.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String nome = listaDislike.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                    setMarker(latit, longi, nome, false, position);
                    listaDislike.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    setUpMap();
                }
            });
            break;
        case R.id.rota:
            //AQUI ATIVA O BOTAO CALCULAR ROTA
            //showDist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            calcRout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            yourDest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        break;


    }

}
```

Imagem que ilustra o problema:

[image: Imagem]

Comment: Bem vinda ao StackOverflow! Não está muito clara a sua dúvida, principalmente nesse ponto: "[...] quero que quando eu clique em um o outro soma e não fique sobrepostos como tem ficado [...]". Não conhecemos a sua aplicação Alezinha, é importante que você dê **mais detalhes** sobre o que está acontecendo (e se possível o que já tentou). Talvez ajude se postar uma imagem ilustrando o que quis dizer com esse "sobrepor". Veja como [criar uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Obrigada pelas dicas, fiz um print para ilustrar o "problema"

Comment: IMAGEM PARA ILUSTRAR O PROBLEMA: http://i58.tinypic.com/105t7jd.jpg

Comment: Você deixou comentada a linha que esconde o ListView, ela não esta funcionando? Chegou a tentar alterar a visibilidade com a flag `View.GONE`?

Comment: Wakim, se eu não comentar nenhum listview abre, entretanto se eu comento, fica como na imagem que eu deixei um link aí em cima. Só queria corrigir para quando alguém clique em um listview escoda o outro caso ele esteja aberto.

Comment: Estranho porque são listas diferentes... Fazer `listaLikes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` e `listaDislikes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` deveria funcionar. Porque está modificando a visibilidade de listas diferentes. Consegue saber se as duas referências não apontam para o mesmo objeto?

Comment: Acabei de verificar e as duas listas não apontam para o mesmo objeto. :/

Comment: Poderia colocar o layout? Se estiver usando o `FrameLayout` acho que tive problemas com visibilidade. Mas no caso eu usei algumas animações, o que causava o problema, e um `clearAnimation` acabou resolvendo o problema de visibilidade.

Comment: Consegui resolver de uma maneira meio tosca, só com uma variável booleana :)

Comment: @alezinha, por favor, poste sua solução.

Answer (score 1):

Ao meu ver elas estão sobrepostas porque por padrão quando você não coloca a *visibility* no *layout* fica como *VISIBLE*.

Pelo que eu analisei da sua lógica você só vai alterar as *visibility* quando passar pelo `switch (v.getId())`

Outra dica é utilizar o `View.GONE` que o @Wakim comentou, pois o *INVISIBLE* só esconde o conteudo, porem fica com o espaço da view alocado, já o *GONE* vai limpar e liberar o espaço para que outra *View* possa utilizar. Para maiores informações [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE)